# How to open Access report in a subform/subreport of the main form that houses the controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have this MS Access VBA code, using MS Access 2016.

```VB
Private Sub cmdPreview_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim strReport As String
    Dim strDateField As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim lngView As Long
    Const strcJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

    strReport = "Sales Report V2"
    strDateField = "[OrderDate]"
    lngView = acViewReport

    If IsDate(Me.txtStartDate) Then
        strWhere = "(" & strDateField & " >= " & Format(Me.txtStartDate, strcJetDate) & ")"
    End If
    If IsDate(Me.txtEndDate) Then
        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        End If
        strWhere = strWhere & "(" & strDateField & " < " & Format(Me.txtEndDate + 1, strcJetDate) & ")"
    End If

    If CurrentProject.AllReports(strReport).IsLoaded Then
        DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, lngView, , strWhere

Exit_Handler:
        Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
        If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Cannot open Report"
        End If
        Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

The is the the code is use to make date range form work. The form lets you pick a start date and an end date. You then click a button that calls the above code and the report is generated in an new tab. What I want to achieve but have not been able to figure out so far. Is how to make the report show up in a subform/subreport of the form that contains the date range controls and then from there have a button that is clicked to open the generated report in a new tab or printing or whatever if the user is happy with the selection.

This code is from a tutorial located at [www.allenbrowne.com/casu-08.html](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-08.html)

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Filter` property of the enclosed report:

```
Me!NameOfYourSubreportControl.Report.Filter = strWhere
Me!NameOfYourSubreportControl.Report.FilterOn = True
```

To open the report the normal way, use your existing code.